# How can I bottle using corks?

Tags: beer, bottling, capping, cork

After downing a bottle of [Saison Dupont](http://www.adelaidebiershop.com.au/product.php?productid=16166) last night and wishing to re-use the bottle, I wondered if any home brewers have "capped" their brews using corks?

The bottle looks like it might be re-usable with regular caps, but using corks is a nice flourish.  Corking could mean potentially re-using champagne bottles too.

Has anyone tried corking their brews?  What's involved?

Comment: Keep in mind that the caps for capping on the belgian bottles are slightly bigger than the ones you use for the standard brown american beer bottle.  You can get then (and corking supplies) at your homebrew shop.

Comment: Thanks - I noticed that after posting & edited the question.  I didn't realise larger caps were available though, is there a sizing guide around?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am also in the process of collecting belgian beer bottles for the purpose of bottling.  This has the nice side effect of having to consume some awesome beer to obtain the bottles (I know I can buy them but this way is more fun).

Northern Brewer sells the corks and hoods:

[Corks](http://www.northernbrewer.com/brewing/brewing-equipment/bottling/bottle-caps-closures/corks-for-belgian-beer-bottles-30-ct.html), 
[Wire Hoods](http://www.northernbrewer.com/brewing/brewing-equipment/bottling/bottle-caps-closures/hooded-wires-for-belgian-beer-bottles-60-ct.html)

Luckily I already have this corker from my wine making adventure:
[Double Lever corker](http://www.northernbrewer.com/winemaking/double-lever-corker.html)

And they say this tool is helpful for tightening the hoods but not necessary:
[Champagne Wire Tightener](http://www.northernbrewer.com/winemaking/champagne-wire-tightener.html)

Now I've only gone so far as to look for the equipment and the process, I haven't tried this yet but I've read the post on [BYO here](http://www.byo.com/stories/beer-styles/article/indices/11-beer-styles/1941-corking-belgians).  It seems the process is the same as bottle in regular bottles, prime with the correct amount of sugar and the key is getting the cork depth set correctly.  Can't wait to get enough bottles to try this!

Comment: There was also a good episode of Brewing TV that showed how to cork bottles. http://www.brewingtv.com/episodes/2010/8/3/brewing-tv-episode-13-full-sail-brewers-sharebiere-de-garde.html